# to be _ but _ structure

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

Elusive means hard to find or capture. I read a sentence in the newspaper today which was

> *They were asked to go to Jhalwar on April 5 to be tested but proved elusive.*

I am confused in the meaning of this sentence. *To be tested* means so that the people can be tested. I am confused in the second part which is *but proved elusive.*

Does it mean that people ran away before being tested? How to read such a sentence with a structure like this?

Comment: It's certainly an interesting choice of words -- I would say that your interpretation is correct: that they ran away before being tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the quote:
[TheHindu.com Jhalwar](https://tinyurl.com/ybqgpk8m)
"On an impulse, Dr. Raees decided to test the family members who had handled the body before burial. They were asked to go to Jhalawar on April 5 to be tested but proved elusive. “We had to take the help of the local police and move them by ambulance on April 6 to Jhalawar for testing, which could only be done by the evening, further delaying matters,’ recalled Dr. Raees."

It clearly means that the individuals told to report for testing didn't do so, and had to be rounded up by the police.

So, "to be_but" isn't a structure. They were **to be** tested, **but** didn't show up.

Answer (score 1):

Macmillan Dictionary defines the word 'elusive' as *"elusive person or animal is difficult or impossible to find or catch."* e.g., *"The rebel leader proved elusive."*

Therefore, your interpretation is correct :

> *"They were asked to go to Jhalwar on April 5 to be tested but proved elusive."*
>
> = *They were asked to go to Jhalwar on April 5 so that they could be tested, but they ran away before being tested.*

Comment: I think the sentence needs a little bit of refinement. It should be something like, "They were asked to...but they (just) disappeared.  When one tells 'an elusive person' it becomes his habit, which is, I think, not what is intended here.

Comment: When we say 'elusive' it sounds like habitually elusive, but let us review if that is the case here. if not, we should use a word like 'disappeared' or so.